# Convert XML response date format from YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00 into DD/MM/YYYY using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

My **XML** response version "1.0" is presenting different collection dates in an array in element  and the format is 2019-04-04T00:00:00 and I want to use **XSLT** version "1.0" to convert the date format to 04/04/2019 (DD/MM/YYYY) in each recurring  element. I have tried looking for a few solutions or merging this in with other transformations I am doing but it makes them error so I would just like a stylesheet to convert as below and then I will transform the rest separately

RESPONSE XML WITH INCORRECT DATE FORMAT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetFullSiteCollectionsResponse xmlns="http://webservices.whitespacews.com/">
         <GetFullSiteCollectionsResult>
            <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
            <ErrorDescription>Success</ErrorDescription>
            <SuccessFlag>true</SuccessFlag>
            <SiteServices>
               <ApiSiteServiceWithExtraDetails>
                  <SiteService>                     
                     <SiteServiceItemQuantity>1.0000</SiteServiceItemQuantity>
                     <SiteServiceItemID>17222</SiteServiceItemID>
                     <NextCollectionDate>2019-04-04T00:00:00</NextCollectionDate>
                  </SiteService>
                  <RRASSContractRounds>
                     <RRASSContractRound>                                                   
                        <RoundCodeOnly>GDN2</RoundCodeOnly>
                        <DefaultDeviceType>STREET</DefaultDeviceType>
                     </RRASSContractRound>
                  </RRASSContractRounds>
               </ApiSiteServiceWithExtraDetails>
               <ApiSiteServiceWithExtraDetails>
                  <SiteService>                     
                     <SiteServiceItemQuantity>1.0000</SiteServiceItemQuantity>
                     <SiteServiceItemID>17220</SiteServiceItemID>
                     <NextCollectionDate>2019-04-11T00:00:00</NextCollectionDate>
                  </SiteService>
                  <RRASSContractRounds>
                     <RRASSContractRound>                                                
                        <RoundCodeOnly>REC3</RoundCodeOnly>
                        <DefaultDeviceType>STREET</DefaultDeviceType>
                     </RRASSContractRound>
                  </RRASSContractRounds>
               </ApiSiteServiceWithExtraDetails>                              
            </SiteServices>
         </GetFullSiteCollectionsResult>
      </GetFullSiteCollectionsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

DESIRED OUTCOME

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetFullSiteCollectionsResponse xmlns="http://webservices.whitespacews.com/">
         <GetFullSiteCollectionsResult>
            <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
            <ErrorDescription>Success</ErrorDescription>
            <SuccessFlag>true</SuccessFlag>
            <SiteServices>
               <ApiSiteServiceWithExtraDetails>
                  <SiteService>                     
                     <SiteServiceItemQuantity>1.0000</SiteServiceItemQuantity>
                     <SiteServiceItemID>17222</SiteServiceItemID>
                     <NextCollectionDate>04/04/2019</NextCollectionDate>
                  </SiteService>
                  <RRASSContractRounds>
                     <RRASSContractRound>                                
                        <RoundCodeOnly>GDN2</RoundCodeOnly>
                        <DefaultDeviceType>STREET</DefaultDeviceType>
                     </RRASSContractRound>
                  </RRASSContractRounds>
               </ApiSiteServiceWithExtraDetails>
               <ApiSiteServiceWithExtraDetails>
                  <SiteService>                     
                     <SiteServiceItemQuantity>1.0000</SiteServiceItemQuantity>
                     <SiteServiceItemID>17220</SiteServiceItemID>
                     <NextCollectionDate>11/04/2019</NextCollectionDate>
                  </SiteService>
                  <RRASSContractRounds>
                     <RRASSContractRound>                                                                          
                        <RoundCodeOnly>REC3</RoundCodeOnly>
                        <DefaultDeviceType>STREET</DefaultDeviceType>
                     </RRASSContractRound>
                  </RRASSContractRounds>
               </ApiSiteServiceWithExtraDetails>                              
            </SiteServices>
         </GetFullSiteCollectionsResult>
      </GetFullSiteCollectionsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 has no concept of dates. You need to look at this as a (simple) problem in text manipulation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ws="http://webservices.whitespacews.com/"
exclude-result-prefixes="ws">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ws:NextCollectionDate">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 9, 2)"/>
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 6, 2)"/>
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 4)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```